Comma Rules - It sounds weird in my head without the Comma, but can't tell what's wrong about not having one either
I was marked wrong for this - Do we or do we not use commas to separate two nouns that come like this:

From the couch, Alice continued, "I will speak to..."

I thought From the couch would be like some introductory phrase so the Comma is needed. Or is this like a sentence where the comma is not needed.
Also like if someone could give me all the general rules of using comma with examples it'd be really helpful.

The comma after couch is entirely optional - a stylistic choice governed by whether or not you would pause there in speech. I don't know why someone would mark you down for including it. Ignorance, I guess.

It's true that most (but nowhere near all) written instances of from the doorway he could have a comma. But most instances of through the window he could don't have a comma. It's horses for courses.

I'd use << From the couch Alice continued, "I will speak to..." >> or << From the couch, Alice continued "I will speak to...". Many realise that the so-called rules (here, 'comma after introductory phrase [some add if it's 5 words or more]'; 'comma to mark off direct speech') are (1) prescriptive to the point of being arbitrary and (2) often illogical or not really necessary except to sticklers. But we've all had to stick to arbitrary rules when in institutions. I'll add links to the relevant comma quasi-rules, but there are others. And commas are often useful (and needed).

Comma after introductory words/phrases/clauses ... unacceptable, obligatory or optional? // How to punctuate {especially} one-word quotes in a sentence. Also What is the status of 'natural punctuation'? examines more novel usages....

And Grammar: commas and full stops has a decent if traditional overview (from a mainly British perspective).

Mark Twain's rule was that if one reads out the writing, then when one takes a breath, one adds a comma. I forget the rest (semi-colon, colon and full stop) but I have a vague memory that needing to spit and needing tobacco were involved.

Here's a thought: Pauses aren't commas unless you don't know how to read. Just playing Angels' Advocate, because all those people are dead now, but still right in the past.
